# concatenating reducer outputs from SequenceFileOutputFormat

Tags: java, hadoop, reducers

I've got a job that uses 100 reducers config'ed with
setOutputFormat (SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

After the job runs, can I combine all of the part files via
the following command and have things work correctly with
the compression?

hadoop fs -cat output/part* > fullOutput

If not, then what is the preferred way to use multiple
reducers but then lump all of their output into one file?

Many thanks,

--Art

Answer (score 0):

What compression are you using?  With some codecs this will certainly NOT work.  For example, the Lzop codec has headers at the beginning of each file, and so if you just join the files they will have headers interspersed within.  The Lzo (no trailing 'p') codec does not include headers--and until your question I didn't understand why it existed.  I think there is a good chance these parts would concatenate together.

1. If you are able to process your job in a single reducer, you could do that.  Or you could run it with fewer reducers and not worry about combining the files, since you can use the directory as input to your next job.
2. You could run a subsequent MR job (IdentityMapper, IdentityReducer) that combines your output files using a single reducer.
3. You could decompress and then recompress.

   `hadoop dfs -cat output/* | lzop -d -c > full`

I used to worry about this a bit.  Now I use fewer reducers and avoid compression on smaller and temporary files.